# How to change value in UISegmentedControl?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, uisegmentedcontrol

I have set up a segmented control in my project. I want to use it in my settings scene to control whether the orientation is landscape left or landscape right.  I have in set up in my storyboard and here is my code in my SettingsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *orientation;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *orientation;

- (IBAction) setOrientation;

@end
```

and here is my code in SettingsViewController.m

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@implementation SettingsViewController

@synthesize orientation;


- (IBAction)setOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"index = %d\n", orientation.selectedSegmentIndex);
    if (orientation.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"left\n");
    }
    if (orientation.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        NSLog(@"right\n");
    }

}  



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

@end
```

I was wondering why the value isn't changing from 0 to 1 when I select the right side of the control.  Also I was wondering if in my .h I need to declare IBOutlet because I dont use the segmented control as an outlet. I just use it to take in which side is selected and then use that to set the orientation of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Hook it up in the Storyboard to the segmentedControl using valueChanged.

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlChanged:(id)sender {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedC = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;

    if (segmentedC.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
//      NSLog(@"selectedSegmentIndex == 0");
        [self selectFirstSegment];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! It works :) (I would give it an up vote but I dont have a high enough rep to do that :/)

Answer (score 0):

in segment action set the orientation landscape or potriat..and in .m file end of bool orientation type method set

```
return yes;
```

in all .m files .